# CKEditor inline - Aligned bottom not moving when content is added.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor set to inline to edit my content.

The problem: My first editable div is at the very top of the page so the ckeditor panel toolbar is positioned under the div. When I add content to that div the toolbar does not move down and covers up the content of the div. As can be seen in the image below.

[image: toolbar]

I have search the ticketing system and documentation but have not come across a fix.

Comment: This issue was fixed in CKEditor 4.2 if I remember correctly. Which version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Will, A useful solution may be to call jquery UI's .draggable method. This will Let you Drag The Editor out of the Way.

E.g.:
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

To make Something draggable, You have to Get The Element, and then call the method on it.

E.G.:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

Hope I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in a later update of ckEditor make sure you are using an up to date copy and this should work ok now.